# Как пишутся названия школ, с кавычками или без?

Tags: ономастика, кавычки, названия

Скажите, как пишутся названия школ, в кавычках? Например, печально известная американская школа (")Колумбайн(").

**ДОПОЛНЕНО (22.10.2022)**

"Грамота.ру" ответила (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=310005)):

> Написание в кавычках корректно.

Comment: А сколько раз спрашивали? Они ж выборочно отвечают.

Comment: Не менее 10 раз спрашивал у них...

Answer (score 2):

Если у школы есть название, то оно берется в кавычки. Например, частная школа "Орленок".
Если вы знаете, что это именно название школы, то использовать кавычки нужно: школа "Колумбайн".

Comment: На этом сайте нужны правила либо логические аргументы, иначе не верят. То есть ответ надо хоть чуть-чуть обосновать.